# How to add an orange background to top of page

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to add an orange frame to the top of my file. I have attached an image so you know what i'm talking about.

[image: Image Description]

I would like the orange frame to be 35px high. How would I create this in css?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: This post is too vague. Are you asking how to use html? There are plenty of online resources for that. Also, how this is done depends on what exactly you are going for.  If you have a specific use case please upload the code to something like jsfiddle and link it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to add the following code at the top of your page right after the opening *body* tag:

*HTML*

```
<div id="topframe"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
#topframe {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:35px;
    background:orange;
}
```

Or, if you want both at once:

```
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:35px;background:orange;"></div>
```

If you are talking about a background image, this is what you need to add in *body* in your CSS file:

```
background-image:url('path/to/your/image.jpg'); // 35px height orange background
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:top;
```